# How to list all the NIC card address using VC++ version 6?

Tags: visual-c++

i want to list all the NIC card address using a vc++[v6] code.I want to send broadcast messages to all NIC in a system. How can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28VS.85%29.aspx) from the IP Helper API.  This functionality is included via `Iphlpapi.lib` and `Iphlpapi.h`.

> The GetAdaptersAddresses function
>   retrieves the addresses associated
>   with the adapters on the local
>   computer.

You can filter to return IPV4, IPV6 or both.

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28VS.85%29.aspx) WMI class.

If you want to know how to use WMI in Visual C++, follow this [link at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Using_WMI_in_Visual_C__.aspx).